# Transform Results Of Web API Actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

How do I transform the results of my controller actions before the framework formats it?

Suppose I have a controller like:

```
public class Controller : System.Web.Http.ApiController {
    public object GetSomething() {
        return new { value = "something" };
    }
}
```

I want to be able to build something like this:

```
public class ActionResultFilter {
    public object InvokeAction(Action Action) {
        object ActionResult = Action.Invoke();
        if (ActionResult == null) {
            return new { value = "nothing" };
        }
        return ActionResult;
    }
}
```

The key things are that I want to do this after my action is executed, but before the result is converted to an `HttpResponseMessage` so that I don't have to handle serialization.

Here's what I've tried:

- `ActionFilterAttribute` is too late. The result is already an `HttpResponseMessage`.
- I don't know how to invoke actions from `IHttpActionInvoker`. Plus, I don't want to return an `HttpResponseMessage`.
- `ControllerActionInvoker` doesn't seem to give me a response anywhere.

From http://www.asp.net/posters/web-api/asp.net-web-api-poster-grayscale.pdf, it looks like I want something between Controller Action and OnActionExecuted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the [`HttpContent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.content%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) in [`HttpResponseMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and check if it is an [`ObjectContent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.objectcontent%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) within an [`ActionFilterAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

```
public class YourFilterNameAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var objectContent = context.Response.Content as ObjectContent
        if(objectContent != null && objectContent.Value == null) 
        {
            context.Response = context.Request
                                      .CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, 
                                                      new { value = "nothing" });
        }
    }
}
```

This is a minimal example (with minimal error checking and a very limited scenario) but it should get your started on the right path when it comes to intercepting and rewriting responses with action filters.